# Transmission error codes

Tags: dtc

Would overfilled transmission fluid cause the engine to surge and trigger codes P0700 and P0720? When the codes are triggered, it seems as though the transmission is stuck in 3rd gear causing the rpm’s to go way up

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?